# GX Model file is invalid while opening the GX Models in Studio

Tags: guidewire

Getting the pop up dialog box with below message

The GX Model file is not valid

Argument for @NotNull parameter 'V1' of gw/gosu/ij/util/VersionNumberUtil.compare must not be null.

Getting this message for all the GX models including OOTB files. Any help would be appreciated ?

Comment: What product and version are you using? Without more context is may be difficult to provided an informed answer.

Usually when I have seen these errors in the past it means that some file(s) outside of the configuration folder were changed/modified/removed.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an internal IntelliJ (GW Studio) error encountered while attempting to parse the GX model file in Studio. It's a trivial error and likely that either one of your IntelliJ plugin jars is messed up or you are trying to use mismatched versions of the studio plugin and the core InsuranceSuite platform code.

The `VersionNumberUtil.compare` method tracks to the `ij-gosu-xxx-rc.jar` file that is a part of the `repository` package including compiled platform code from Guidewire. The `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull` annotation is in play here and reports the error when one of the operands to this function is null. Most likely IJ is unable to find the `Gosu version` for your project and passes the parameter as null when trying to check if the Gosu version is higher than a certain version.

My first attempt to fix this would be to clean the studio installation by running `gwb cleanIdea` followed by `gwb idea`. This would clean and regenerate the Studio IJ project and likely fix the error provided your platform code isn't compromised.

Otherwise, there can be several reasons for this issue including an incomplete unzip of the platform code or an anti-virus or scanning tool deleting one of the jar files as a false positive. In any case, one would not expect to see this error on a clean and fresh extract of Insurance Suite.